# Openwrt/Raspberry: lost the connection after periodic connection test through usb wifi adapter

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, wifi, openwrt, usb-drive

I'm developing a script that permits to connect to the internet through a Mediatek MT7612U wifi adapter (Alfa AWUS036ACM) and making some connection tests using speedtest-cli, iperf3 ...
My script is running under OpenWrt linux system. I installed Openwrt in a raspberry PI4 Model B. I plugged to the raspberry two wifi adapter (Alfa AWUS036ACM with Mediatek MT7612U chipset).
The script is running permenantly, and making periodically some connection Tests. After a period of time I lost the connection.

When I checked the system log I found this error reported by the kernel:

***kern.err kernel: [ 1929.020945] mt76x2u 2-1:1.0: error: mt76x02u_mcu_wait_resp failed with -110***

The issue disappear when I reboot the system. But I need to fix it without rebooting.
I tried to reset the usb device with ioctl USBDEVFS_RESET but that caused the lost of corresponding network interfaces,
I tried also to poweroff/poweron the usb device with commands like that:

```
echo disabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/wakeup
echo enabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/wakeup
```

but the issue is not fixed

I tried also to unbind/bind the usb device

```
echo '2-1' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
echo '2-1' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind
```

and the issue is not fixed also

Has someone an idea why I got this blocker issue. Is there an idea to fix or bypass it without the need to reboot the system.

Comment: Did you figure out the source of your problem? I seem to have exactly the [same problem](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/140330/help-debugging-random-usb-wifi-disconnect-with-alfa-awus036acm-chipset-mt7612u)…
Seems related to [this](https://github.com/openwrt/mt76/issues/405), with recommended fix: `echo 1 > /sys/module/mt76_usb/parameters/disable_usb_sg` (testing it now)

Answer (score 0):

I've also been getting this exact issue. I've also been using the Alfa AWUS036ACM.

I've tried unplugging the adapter and that resets it, then after putting it into monitor mode again it works for a short while before failing with the issue OP has again. I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3b

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A late answer, and not much of answer, but there seems to be an open bug,
discussed on GitHub (https://github.com/openwrt/mt76/issues/405).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).